# Simple getColumnName(0) call throws Invalid column index: getValidColumnIndex

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to write a JTable that takes the data from a ResultSet and uses that to create a dynamic sized table with appropriate column names and row data values from the ResultSet but I can't get JDBC to get the column names for me dynamically.

I know my select statement is good! I can print the results out easily with my ResultPrinter class that I wrote but I can't seem to get the column names for some reason.

The code: http://pastebin.com/SSNdCkNu

The output:

```
Connected to DB!  
SNUM, SNAME, STATUS, CITY, SUPPLIERS_ID_SEQ // printed by static Suppliers class
Columns: 5 // result set shows there are 5 valid columns as expected
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index: getValidColumnIndex
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetMetaData.getValidColumnIndex(OracleResultSetMetaData.java:138)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetMetaData.getColumnName(OracleResultSetMetaData.java:306)
at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

JDBC column indexes start from 1 and not 0. As far as possible, it is better to retrieve data using column names to avoid hard dependency on the order of columns in the results.

Comment: Wow that's pretty ridiculous. Or maybe I'm just embarassed because the error was so simple. Either way I figured programatically getting the number of columns and then getting their name was a good method? Because if the user does a select statement which doesn't use all the columns, then there's no way for me to know the names of the columns that were selected or not.

Comment: You can use the ResultSetMetaData to know the columns present in a given resultset along with their datatype.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing :)

I used the hard coded 0 for simplicity because I was trying to find the origin of the bug.

Answer (score 4):

Column index starts by 1. So increase your variable pointing column variable by 1.